# Name cannot begin with the '<' character hexadecimal value 0x3c

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I'm trying to get some data from a WebService using SOAP request. The SOAP body should contain an SQL query. Whenever I'm using the `<` character it causes the above mentioned error at `SOAPReqBody.LoadXml()`. How can I fix this?

```
HttpWebRequest request = CreateSOAPWebRequest();
XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();
SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
 <soap:Body>  
    <Query xmlns=""http://LifaOIS.DK/OISService"">
      <UID>" + uid + @"</UID>
      <PWD>" + pwd + @"</PWD>
      <SQL>" + sql + @"</SQL>
      <Meta>" + meta + @"</Meta>
     </Query>
  </soap:Body>  
</soap:Envelope>");
```

Comment: The code posted is correcrt proviced the variables uid, pwd, sql, and meta do not contain illegal xml characters.   See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references.  Look only at the 5 xml special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your `sql` in `<![CDATA[...]]>`?

Like:

```
<SQL><![CDATA[" + sql + @"]]></SQL>
```

Instead of

```
<SQL>" + sql + @"</SQL>
```

See [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) for more details.

Comment: I knew nothing about <![CDATA[]]>. I have jus tried it and it has solved the problem.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly but if you really have to carry a SQL query within the message payload and the less than '<' character is a problem within the XML and you can't control packing and unpacking of the payload, then you might like to consider using BETWEEN...

```
WHERE field NOT EQUAL minValue AND field BETWEEN minvalue AND upperValue
```

Note that BETWEEN's from and to values are inclusive - hence the need for the exclusion of minValue